# overwrite bootstrap css rules not working, css files and rules seen but properties ignored

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates, django-bootstrap3

I use bootswatch v3.3.6 and django 1.11.2

I want to make a button full width inside a bootstrap's table column, but something very peculiar happens as can be seen in the following pictures:

[image]

I want to make that blue button full width. I have added a `btn-buy` class to my template and the corresponding css:

```
.btn-buy.btn-primary {
    "width": 100%;
}
```

The problem is that `width` property is ignored as the red arrow points. However if I click on `store.css` :

[image]

and write on the firebug console the property:

[image]

then the modification is applied correctly:

[image]

No matter how I write the class `btn-buy` or e.g if I make it an id instead, the result is the same.

This is the relevant DTL code:

```
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                        <div id="plan-thumb" class="thumbnail">
                            <h3>Name</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <h4 align="center">{{ plan.description }}</h4>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Calls per minute: {{ plan.requests_per_minute }}</li>
                                <li>Calls per day: {{ plan.requests_per_day }}</li>
                                <li>Calls per minute: {{ plan.requests_per_month }}</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5 class="pull-middle">Price per month: {{ plan.price }}$</h5>
                            <hr>
                                <div class="bottom-align-text">
                                        {# todo this should be JS instead of new url, pushing a popup of terms etc #}
                                        <button type="button" class=" btn-buy btn-primary" href="#"> Buy
                                            {# href="{% url 'store:buy' plan_id=plan.id %}"> #}
                                        </button>
                                </div>
                        </div> {# end of thumbnail div #}
                    </div>
```

Any ideas on why my modifications are not being applied automatically?

Comment: In your code block on your question, you have double quotes around the width property. That's not correct CSS syntax - remove the double quotes.

Comment: @stackingjasoncooper You are right! What a stupid mistake :S Thank you very much